# Find all lines with at least 3 special characters in string using Regex

Tags: regex

I'm struggling to find lines that contain 3 or more of a specified character.

Example Problem:

> I want to filter this list to output all lines that contain at least 3
> plus signs

Example Dataset:

```
+1a
+1a +2
+1a +2 +3
+1a +2 +3 +4
+1a +2 +3 +4 +5
```

Desired Output:

```
+1a +2 +3
+1a +2 +3 +4
+1a +2 +3 +4 +5
```

I need to check for plus signs. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Regular Expression:

```
((.*\+.*){3,})
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/1hkFVE/1).

Answer (score 0):

In perl:

```
my $a = "+1 +2";
my $b = "+1 +2 +3";

if($a =~ m/(\+.*){3}/) { print("a: yes\n"); }
else                   { print("a: no\n");  }

if($b =~ m/(\+.*){3}/) { print("b: yes\n"); }
else                   { print("b: no\n");  }
```

outputs:

```
a: no
b: yes
```

The regex used is `(\+.*){3}`. To break down:

```
(\+.*)    --- A plus sign ("\+", "+" is a special symbol in perl, so escape it),
              followed by any characters (".") of zero or arbitrary length ("*").
              Enclose the above character sequence in "(" and ")" to make it a pattern unit.
{3}       --- Repeat the above pattern unit 3 times.
```

The format of regex may differ if using other tools/languages.

Answer (score -1):

If you are not obliged to use a regular expression a simple language construct would seem to be a better choice. In Ruby, for example, `if str.count('+') > 2 ...`. I will assume, however, that a regular expression is needed.

If you want the entire string matched if it contains three or more plus signs you can use the regular expression

```
^(?:[^+\n]*\+){3}.*
```

or

```
^(?=(?:[^+\n]*\+){3}).*
```

See [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/PWUTHh/1) and [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/PWUTHh/2)

(`^(?=(?:.*\+){3}).*`  could be used in place of the latter but is less efficient.) [Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/PWUTHh/3/)

If you merely want any match if (and only if) the string contains three or more plus signs, you may use

```
\+(?:[^+\n]*\+){2}
```

[Demo 4](https://regex101.com/r/PWUTHh/4/)

See the links for a detailed description of the function of each token in each regex.